# How many number of bits stored in a memory location in PDP 11

Tags: assembly, memory-address, addressing, pdp-11

PDP 11 is said to be word addressable which means every data access returns 16 bit data. Suppose I give a read request for address 100 in memory. Will it return 8 bits(LSB) from address 100 and 8bits(MSB) from address 101. And also as PDP 11 has 16 address bits why does it have only 32K memory locations and not 64K memory locations? Is it because it is word addressable(2 bytes for every access)

TIA.

Comment: I doubt that many in here know what a PDP-11 is :(   Most have died off, (both machines and users).

Comment: You might want to ask that question here (and will most likely get a competent answer): https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thankyou guys for the help.

Comment: The PDP-11 is in fact a byte machine. Two bytes are called a word. Conventionally, the amount of memory in a PDP-11 is counted in words, so a PDP-11 with 32 kilowords of memory has 64 kB memory.

Comment: @fuz I don't think that's what he meant. I guess he means that with 16 bit ( word addressed ) the pdp-11 could have been able to address 64k 16 bit words instead, 128kB

Comment: @Tommylee2k Well, the PDP-11 is a byte machine, each address refers to one byte of storage. Thus only 64 kB can be referred to with 16 address lines.

Comment: nothing is dead about the PDP-11, you heard of air traffic control?  And if you dont know the PDP-11 instruction set then that is a shame, the msp430 is a close alternative (clearly a derivative), but other than being in the octal mindset which was understandable for the time, it is still one of the best/cleanest and should be the first instruction set taught...Being actually patent free unlike some others being used in the industry, it would/should be first choice for embedding in products rather than the 8051 and z80 IMO.

Comment: @old_timer Octal is supposed to be good wrt PDP 11 because the various fields (registers and address modes) are all three bits wide. Personally, I could never get my head round it, preferring to do the mental shifts required by hex.

Comment: that is my point there is an active gcc pdp11 backend, but the asm syntax is far from the original, no surprise, and disassembly in hex.  So long as you dont need to examine the machine code you are probably okay having it in hex otherwise break out the pencil and paper...

Comment: I assume octal was easier to swallow back then, understand that other than the base 60-ish hours/minutes/seconds, using other bases was foreign.  hex makes more sense groups of four rather than groups of three but using letters as numbers is IMO an evolutionary step.  dont know I was barely alive when this was going on if alive at all...

Comment: Looking at a PDP-11 manual "16-bit (two 8-bit bytes) direct addressing of 32K words or 64K bytes (K = 1024)"  as fuz has been trying to tell you

Answer (score 3):

Here's some additional information on memory addressing for hardware like the 11/70 and 11/84 that allowed the largest physical memory available of any PDP-11 models. (Pardon the inconsistent formatting. I'm having to work within the limits of Stackoverflow's restrictions on Markdown syntax.)

> The PDP-11/70 uses 22 bits for addressing physical memory. This
>   represents a total of 2<sup>22</sup> (over 4 million) byte locations.
>
> Of the over 4 million byte locations possible with the 22-bit address,
>   the top 256K are used to reference the UNIBUS rather than physical
>   memory. Maximum main memory is therefore 2<sup>22</sup> - 2<sup>18</sup>, or a total of 3,932,160 bytes.
>
> Three separate address spaces are used with the PDP-11/70. Main
>   memory uses 22-blt addresses, the UNIBUS uses an 18-bit address,
>   and the computer program uses a 16-bit virtual address. The
>   information is summarized below:

```
                                   Bytes

16 bits  program virtual space     2^16 = 64K
18 bits  UNIBUS space              2^18 = 256K
22 bits  physical memory space     4 million
```

(Taken from http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp11/handbooks/PDP11_Handbook1979.pdf)

As far as program virtual address space goes, some PDP-11 models, such as the PDP-11/45, 11/70, and 11/84, had hardware support for two separate 16-bit virtual address spaces, one for program instructions, and one for data. This effectively doubled the virtual address space for these machines. In the days when I was programming PDP-11 systems, it was common to refer to these two address spaces as *I-Space* and *D-Space*.

Answer (score 1):

The PDP-11 is a byte addressed machine but it has a 16 bit data bus. If you issue a word read to address 100, it will return you the two bytes at 100 and 101. The PDP-11 is little endian so the byte at 100 is the low byte.

The PDP-11 has instructions for manipulating bytes and words, a byte read would only read the byte at address 100 to the low byte of the specified register. I think there were special instructions to swap the low and high bytes of a register.

If you issued a word read to an odd address e.g. `mov 101,r1` I think it generated an odd address exception. That may be incorrect or not true of all models, but I clearly remember having to explain to somebody who was working on a PDP-11 system back in about 1989 what an odd address trap was.

Comment: www.dbit.com/pub/pdp11/faq/faq.pages/PDPinst.html  google pdp11 odd address trap, first hit, all you said and more.  SWAB (swap bytes, is shown there too, good call on that too).

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to fuz on this one.

The pdp11 is a byte based machine the definition of a word is 16 bits (very odd for a heavily octal machine).

Taking a quick look at a DEC document

> 16-bit word (two 8-bit bytes) direct addressing of 32K words or 64K
>   bytes (K = 1024)

The above from a PDP11/34 document but since you are talking about 32K this should suffice (dont have to dig through every pdp11/lsi11 document).

When working on a simulator remember there being 18 bit address/bus which makes a lot more sense for such a heavily octal oriented time period and/or company/product.

Ahh yes, extended addressing 18 bits.

The document continues to use words as a unit for memory, understand that is a convention, understand your history here, today we use bytes, but actually if you are in the memory world they use bits they dont use bytes to define the size of a memory.  It may be very well, would have to look  that the data bus was 16 bits and the address was word based, that doesnt mean anything with respect to what the processor can do, the processor you are reading this on probably has a 32 or 64 bit wide data bus does that mean that it is word or double word (double or quad depending on the architecture and its common terminology) addressable only?  Nope.